# Standard date format vs custom date format

Tags: c#, date, format, date-format

I provide an application where the user is able to format any date by any given format string.
The problem I discovered is the following:

Let's say, I want to format the date as single month index. This is, for today "6". 
But:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") => 26.06.2014<br/>
DateTime.Today.ToString("M") => **26 Juni**<br/>
DateTime.Today.ToString("dM") => 266
```

Using msdn I found out, that "M" is - if used singular - a standard format specifier, but if used with other chars, its a custom format specifier ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

**Question**: How to force interpreting the given format string always as custom format specifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second case, you need to specify that the `M` is a custom format specifier by providing the `%` sign:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("%M"));
```

Prints:

> 6

According to [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MSDN: Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), the `%` sign:

> Defines the following character as a custom format specifier.

I guess if the user can specify the string, you should always escape it with `%`.

Comment: Here's a link to the relevant section of the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Comment: That's it. Thanks.
I read this section before answering, but obiously didn't get it.